# Bi-annual Salesforce MVP Nominations are Open - Summer '17

Tags: discussion, mvp

**Public service announcement:**

The [MVP nominations](https://www.salesforce.com/blog/2017/07/salesforce-mvp-summer-17-nominations.html) are open from now until August 7, 2017.

Feel free to nominate those who have made an exceptional contribution to the SFSE community. That could be [users](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=year) or [moderators](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) or anyone else who has helped you on your way.

See also: [Top 5 Things to Know About How We Choose Our MVPs](https://www.salesforce.com/blog/2016/02/how-we-choose-salesforce-mvps.html)